# route website through proxy

Tags: html, youtube, proxy

I am making a website for school and am going to embed some youtube videos on my site. At my school youtube is blocked and I can get past it by using a vpn, however, the blocks are pretty good and block many proxies. Is there any way that I can in my HTML route the videos through a proxy or something so that my videos will always be accessable as long as the proxy isn't blocked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it using only HTML. You'll need a web server that downloads the videos and makes them available for the client to download. That's not cheap/convenient.

You can put them on Drive or Dropbox and reproduce them using a web player such as JW Player.